# media Query for macbook pro 15"

Tags: css, web, responsive-design, media-queries, retina-display

I'm trying to apply media query for laptop 15" and smaller with no success.

Here is my media query:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { }
```

And:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { }
```

I works for 13inch macbook pro but no for the 15".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a problem with `min-device-width`, as it should only work on mobile devices (tablet, smartphones):

> min-device-width

Try using those (without `-device-`) so you can test it on your computer's browser.

> min-width or max-width

**Styles for Desktop**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

   /* Styles for Desktops */
 }
```

Also add inside  tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, 
for more reference regarding difference between device-width and width read this article https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/

Answer (score 4):

```
 /*--cover up mac , mac-book---*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px) {}

/*--mac book pro , and mac-book retina display screen---*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2560px) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Retina Display media queries

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only 
screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { styles }
```