# Media query CSS is not get applied in Macbook

Tags: css, ios, macos, media-queries

I have written the below media query to target screen resolutions 2560px and higher

```
@media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  .singleVideoPlayerScreen .customVideoControls--box--Left {
    width: 14%;
  }
}
```

And this is my screen resolution:

[image: screen resolution]

But when I check in my Macbook then the media query rule is not getting applied and if I change the code as follows:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2560px) {
  .singleVideoPlayerScreen .customVideoControls--box--Left {
    width: 14%;
  }
}
```

then the CSS is getting applied to the screen with 1920px resolution but still not in the 2560px resolution.

Please advice

BTW I have already checked these answers and it didn't help:
[SO question link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40626945/macbook-pro-not-accepting-media-query-using-css)
[SO question link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538086/media-query-for-macbook-pro-15)

Comment: Do you have any zoom set in your browser?

Comment: No, there is no zoom

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071138/why-does-viewport-width-not-match-the-actual-display-width

Comment: Wow, so setting the min-width to 1440px worked like a charm. Thanks @Gerfried